# Cannot Import modules from Nuxt.js middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I try to import modules from middleware, type error occurs and the Nuxt application does not start.
The code is as follows.
The application uses nuxt-community / starter-template.

nuxt.config.js (jsut add only router on default file)

```
module.exports = {  
router: {  
   middleware: 'auth'
},
```

middleware/auth.js

```
import { Auth } from aws-amplify
export default ( ) => {
    const user =  Auth.currentUserInfo()
    console.log(user)
}
```

run `npm run dev` (error occur)
[Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0K1N.jpg)

Thanks your help!

Comment: Is this exactly how your code is written? aws-amplify should be in quotes, e.g. 'aws-amplify'

Comment: I've run into a similar problem. Apparently some core libraries get "blocked" by Nuxt middleware, such as '`fs`